# How can I get Azure App Service to add a custom HTTP response header on a static site?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure site that consists only of static html pages. How can I set the cache-control header in the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following code to add your custom cache-control header:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear /> <!-- Gets rid of the other unwanted headers -->
        <add name="cache-control" value="XXXXX" />
      </customHeaders>
      <redirectHeaders>
        <clear />
      </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>    
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://boyet.com/blog/making-an-azure-static-website-even-more-secure/).

Comment: Thanks! (I don't think the redirect headers bit is needed though)